# Visual Studio 2019 Problem - Controller Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net 2.2 Core MVC (Career/JobBoard) site that I originally developed on VS2017.  Everything is working fine on my local machine and in production (Azure).

The other day, I decided to install VS2019 and develop using that updated tool.  I opened my site and most of the site seemed to work fine.  But then I encountered a problem:

One of my controllers no longer routes properly.  No matter what action I call, I get a

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

[image: 404error]

which is very weird bc I have custom error handling pages which don't get run.  The other weird thing is the Physical Path seems to be missing the controller/view name altogether.

I put debug breakpoints in the Controller constructor and it never even gets hit when I try to go to any action in that controller.

My other controllers/views seem to work just fine.  The weird thing is I can create a custom route

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Details",
   template: "testposting/details/{hash_id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Posting", action = "Details" }
);
```

and THAT works fine.

I removed any other custom routing that I had in Startup.cs to make sure there was nothing conflicting.

Also, everything still works fine in production (Azure).  Only a problem on local VS2019.

I've cleaned and rebuilt the project and solution.  I've deleted /bin files.  Nothing seems to fix this problem except reverting back to VS2017 where it all works fine.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using any route attributes? Post the relevant controller/action signatures. Also you can try this route debugger: https://edi.wang/post/2020/4/29/my-aspnet-core-route-debugger-middleware

Comment: not using route attributes in the controller/action.  again, everything works fine in production and vs2017.  i will look into the debugger

Comment: Can you show the code of your `Posting` controller? And do you apply any route constraints?

Comment: @FeiHan Its a pretty big chunk of code but just to check, I deleted everything out of that controller except my Details action and it still gives me a 404 error.  Also, if I rename my Controller to Posting2, everything works just fine in VS2019